# Use sed to replace word in 2-line pattern

Tags: perl, sed, substitution

I try to use sed to replace a word in a 2-line pattern with another word. When in one line the pattern 'MACRO "something"' is found then in the next line replace 'BLOCK' with 'CORE'. The "something" is to be put into a reference and printed out as well.

My input data:

```
MACRO ABCD
  CLASS BLOCK ;
  SYMMETRY X Y ;
```

Desired outcome:

```
MACRO ABCD
  CLASS CORE ;
  SYMMETRY X Y ;
```

My attempt in sed so far:

```
sed 's/MACRO \([A-Za-z0-9]*\)/,/  CLASS BLOCK ;/MACRO \1\n  CLASS CORE ;/g' input.txt
```

The above did not work giving message:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 30: unknown option to `s'
```

What am I missing?

I'm open to one-liner solutions in perl as well.

Thanks,
Gert

Comment: So you want to send "ABCD" to `stdout` while altering the file in place?

Answer (score 3):

Using a perl one-liner in slurp mode:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/MACRO \w+\n  CLASS \KBLOCK ;/CORE ;/g' input.txt
```

Or using a streaming example:

```
perl -pe '
    s/^\s*\bCLASS \KBLOCK ;/CORE ;/ if $prev;
    $prev = $_ =~ /^MACRO \w+$/
  ' input.txt
```

#### Explanation:

**Switches**:

- `-0777`: Slurp files whole
- `-p`: Creates a `while(<>){...; print}` loop for each line in your input file.
- `-e`: Tells `perl` to execute the code on command line.

Answer (score 3):

> When in one line the pattern 'MACRO "something"' is found then in the
>   next line replace 'BLOCK' with 'CORE'.

`sed` works on *lines* of input.  If you want to perform substitution on the next line of a specified pattern, then you need to add that to the pattern space before being able to do so.

The following might work for you:

```
sed '/MACRO/{N;s/\(CLASS \)BLOCK/\1CORE/;}' filename
```

Quoting from the documentation:

> `N'
>
> ```
>  Add a newline to the pattern space, then append the next line of
>  input to the pattern space.  If there is no more input then sed
>  exits without processing any more commands.
> ```

---

If you want to make use of address range as in your attempt, then you need:

```
 sed '/MACRO/,/CLASS BLOCK/{s/\(CLASS\) BLOCK/\1 CORE/}' filename
```

I'm not sure why do you need a backreference for substituting the macro name.

Comment: This would likely work in most cases however if the replacement pattern were in the line containing `MACRO` then the second line would not be amended. Perhaps `sed '/MACRO/{n;s/\(CLASS \)BLOCK/\1CORE/;}' file` would fit the bill?

Answer (score 0):

This could do it

```
#!awk -f
BEGIN {
  RS = ";"
}
/MACRO/ {
  sub("BLOCK", "CORE")
}
{
  printf s++ ? ";" $0 : $0
}
```

- "line" ends with `;`
- sub `BLOCK` for `CORE` in "lines" with `MACRO`
- print `;` followed by "line" unless first line

Answer (score 0):

You could try this awk command also,

```
awk '{print}/MACRO/ {getline; sub (/BLOCK/,"CORE");{print}}' file
```

It prints all the lines as it is and do the replacing action on seeing a word MACRO on a line.

Comment: `awk '1; /MACRO/ {getline;sub(/BLOCK/,"CORE");print}'` is the same as you have posted, but some cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Since `getline` has so many pitfall I try not to use it, so:

```
awk '/MACRO/ {a++} a==1 {sub(/BLOCK/,"CORE")}1' file
MACRO ABCD
  CLASS CORE ;
  SYMMETRY X Y ;
```